# AzureADB2C GetAccessTokenForUserAsync Error "The scope 'user.read' provided in the request is not supported"

Tags: blazor, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm attempting create a Blazor Application that integrates with the Microsoft Graph API (specifically OneDrive) and uses Azure AD B2C for authentication.

I'm using  Microsoft.Identity.Web 0.3.1-preview

**The Setup.cs is as follows:**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Configuration to sign-in users with Azure AD B2C
        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C")
             .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" })
             .AddMicrosoftGraph("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta")
             .AddInMemoryTokenCaches(); 
...
```

**The Service then uses ITokenAcquisition** to request a token as follows:

```
public MyService(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition, IOptions<WebOptions> webOptionValue, 
                          AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider)
    {
                string result = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "user.read" });
```

I'm authenticating using a Microsoft linked account and can see the live.com claim in the AuthenticationStateProvider.

Passing in the basic user.read to GetAccessTokenForUserAsync results in an exception " The scope 'user.read' provided in the request is not supported". I've tried specifying the scope as https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read however this just returns null.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens that are issued by Azure AD B2C are intended for use by an Azure AD B2C-registered client with an Azure AD B2C-registered resource.

Microsoft Graph API is not an Azure AD B2C-registered resource so the `https://graph.microsoft.com/` scopes aren't supported.

Alternatively, you might consider passing the access token as [the **idp_access_token** claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-custom) through, from the Microsoft identity provider to your Azure AD B2C-registered client.

A custom policy is needed for [the Microsoft identity provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga) to [pass this through](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63501670/7378174).

Comment: Thanks Chris - I am able to access the IDP_ACCESS_TOKEN through the AuthenticationStateProvider object without modifications to the Identity Provider. The basic graph API calls work using this however access to OneDrive (graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request().AddAsync) results in "The application ID does not exist." error. Any idea why this occurs?

Comment: Hi @Rucesse I believe this error message hides an invalid permission. You might have to request the `Files.ReadWrite` (or higher) permission from the Microsoft identity provider. I don't believe that this can be done via a built-in flow so you might have to consider a custom policy as per the above answer.